# How can I use sum() value in SQL Server multiple times?

Tags: sql-server

My table is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tableStore] 
(
    [ID] INT NULL,
    [Price] DECIMAL(18, 2) NULL,
    [Discount] DECIMAL(18, 2) DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Table] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
);
```

How can I use `SUM()` value in SQL Server multiple times?

Like this:

```
SELECT
    SUM(tableStore.Price) AS PriceTotal,
    PriceTotal - SUM(tableStore.Discount)
FROM 
    tableStore
```

How can I use this column `[PriceTotal]` for another operation?

Comment: `SUM(tableStore.Price) - SUM(StoreTable.Discount)`. Alternatively use a derived table or CTE

Comment: I would add it to a table either with an incrementalId or a timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the PriceTotal using a subquery

```sql
select 
    PriceTotal - DiscountTotal 
from 
    (select sum(price) as PriceTotal, sum(discount) as DiscountTotal 
     from tableStore) as A;
```

Alternatively, you can use the `WITH` keyword to get a common table expression with the `PriceTotal` column:

```sql
with PriceTotalTable as 
(
    select sum(price) as pt 
    from tableStore
) 
select pt 
from PriceTotalTable;
```

Above queries are tested in MySQL